# Is there a more cleaner or elegant way to pass multiple parameters to SQL stored procedure using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, stored-procedures

Right now I am passing multiple parameters to a stored procedure with Entity Framework and it looks like this..

```
public long AddDealer(Dealer dealer)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(AWJE.Database.SqlQuery<Dealer>(
            "usp_InsertDealer @Name, @Description",
            new SqlParameter("@DealerID", dealer.DealerID).Value,
            new SqlParameter("@Name", dealer.Name),
            new SqlParameter("@Description", dealer.Description)
            ));
    }
```

is there a more elegant or cleaner way to pass multiple parameters, instead of the way shown? If I come across other stored procedures that have many more parameters to be passed then this way looks like it will get messy real quick.

Comment: are you using code first or have you generated an edmx?  i know in the past i have added a stored procedure to my edmx and then been able to call it just like a function. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896231(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @kmacdonald, I wrote the stored procedures and tables in SSMS and then generated from the database.

Comment: I don't know what exactly `usp_InsertAddress` does but it looks to me that you could just use an entity and either add it to the context and `SaveChanges()` or, if you need to use stored procs for CUD operations, map stored procs accordingly. Also EF will try to materialize the result of the stored procedure to `IEnumerable<Address>` so I am not quite sure how `Convert.ToInt32()` is supposed to work here.

Comment: @Pawel, I noticed there was a flaw with what I wrote. I haven't been able to test anything yet as I have a lot more methods to write. The usp_InsertAddress is a crud operation and returns the new ID, that's why I have it converting the return value to an Int32, which is wrong and that'll be my next question because I kind of changed the method. What I am going to do is edit that method with an updated version on how I think I am to get the returned ID

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code example is clearly not a working example:

1. I don't see how you can convert an object of type `Dealer` to an `int`.
2. If your method is expected to return a `long`, then why convert the result of the stored procedure to an `int`?
3. You are passing a `@DealerID` parameter, but it's not part of the SP call.
4. Not sure why one of the `SqlParameter`s has a call to `.Value` add onto it.

So, let me adjust it, and assume that your starting point is instead something like this:

```
public long AddDealer(Dealer dealer)
{
    return AWJE.Database.SqlQuery<Dealer>(
        "usp_InsertDealer @Name, @Description",
        new SqlParameter("@Name", dealer.Name),
        new SqlParameter("@Description", dealer.Description)
        ).DealerID;
}
```

Or maybe you decide that the SP returns a `long` directly, like this:

```
public long AddDealer(Dealer dealer)
{
    return AWJE.Database.SqlQuery<long>(
        "usp_InsertDealer @Name, @Description",
        new SqlParameter("@Name", dealer.Name),
        new SqlParameter("@Description", dealer.Description)
        );
}
```

Either way, the only simplification I see is that you can change the invocation to `SqlQuery` so that positional parameters are used instead of named parameters.  Making that change allows you to forego the creation of explicit `SqlParameter` instances.  The call could then be simplified to this:

```
public long AddDealer(Dealer dealer)
{
    return AWJE.Database.SqlQuery<long>(
        "usp_InsertDealer @Name, @Description",
        dealer.Name,
        dealer.Description
        );
}
```

... where how you name `@Name` or `@Description` no longer has any importance, but you have to make sure you pass in the parameter values in the right order.

Apart from this, I don't know that you can make this cleaner or more elegant.

Comment: Thank you for clearing things up, you are correct, it wasn't a working example because I haven't had a chance to test because I have a lot more of those to write and was going to test latter, so I appreciate the fix. So either of those first 2 code blocks will give me the returning ID from the stored procedure? and just being able to remove the named parameters and using positional parameters has definitely cleaned it up more.